# Value in an array between two numbers in python

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy

So making a title that actually explains what i want is harder than i thought, so here goes me explaining it.

I have an array filled with zeros that adds values every time a condition is met, so after 1 time step iteration i get something like this (minus the headers):

current_array =

```
bubble_size y_coord
14040       42
3943        71
6345        11
0           0
0           0
....
```

After this time step is complete this current_array gets set as previous_array and is wiped with zeros because there is not a guaranteed number of entries each time.

NOW the real question is i want to be able to check all rows in the first column of the previous_array and see if the current bubble size is within say 5% either side and if so i want to take the current y position away for the value associated with the matching bubble size number in the previous_array's second column.

currently i have something like;

```
if bubble_size in current_array[:, 0]:
    do_whatever
```

but i don't know how to pull out the associated y_coord without using a loop, which i am fine with doing (there is about 100 rows to the array and atleast 1000 time steps so i want to make it as efficient as possible) but would like to avoid

i have included my thoughts on the for loop (note the current and previous_array are actually current and previous_frame)

```
for y in range (0, array_size):
    if bubble_size >> previous_frame[y,0] *.95 &&<< previous_frame[y, 0] *1.05:
        distance_travelled = current_y_coord - previous_frame[y,0]
        y = y + 1
```

Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Could you provide an example of what you want the output to look like?

Comment: Is using Numba or Cython not an option?

Answer (score 0):

I probably did not get your issue here but if you want to first check if the bubble size is in between the same row element 95 % you can use the following:

```
import numpy as np

def apply(p, c):  # For each element check the bubblesize grow
    if(p*0.95 < c < p*1.05):
        return 1
    else:
        return 0


def dist(p, c):  # Calculate the distance
    return c-p

def update(prev, cur):
    assert isinstance(
        cur, np.ndarray), 'Current array is not a valid numpy array'
    assert isinstance(
        prev, np.ndarray), 'Previous array is not a valid numpy array'
    assert prev.shape == cur.shape, 'Arrays size mismatch'

    applyvec = np.vectorize(apply)
    toapply = applyvec(prev[:, 0], cur[:, 0])

    print(toapply)

    distvec = np.vectorize(dist)
    distance = distvec(prev[:, 1], cur[:, 1])

    print(distance)


current = np.array([[14040, 42],
                [3943,71],
                [6345,11],
                [0,0],
                [0,0]])

previous = np.array([[14039, 32],
                [3942,61],
                [6344,1],
                [0,0],
                [0,0]])

update(previous,current)
```

PS: Please, could you tell us what is the final array you look for based on my examples?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it (correct me if Im wrong):

- You have a current bubble size (integer) and a current y value (integer)
- You have a 2D array (`prev_array`) that contains bubble sizes and y coords
- You want to check whether your current bubble size is within 5% (either way) of each stored bubble size in `prev_array`
- If they are within range, subtract your current y value from the stored y coord
- This will result in a new array, containing only bubble sizes that are within range, and the newly subtracted y value
- You want to do this without an explicit loop

You can do that using boolean indexing in numpy...

Setup the previous array:

```
prev_array = np.array([[14040, 42], [3943, 71], [6345, 11], [3945,0], [0,0]])

prev_array

array([[14040,    42],
       [ 3943,    71],
       [ 6345,    11],
       [ 3945,     0],
       [    0,     0]])
```

You have your stored bubble size you want to use for comparison, and a current y coord value:

```
bubble_size = 3750
cur_y = 10
```

Next we can create a boolean mask where we only select rows of `prev_array` that meets the 5% criteria:

```
ind = (bubble_size > prev_array[:,0]*.95) & (bubble_size < prev_array[:,0]*1.05)

# ind is a boolean array that looks like this: [False,  True, False,  True, False]
```

Then we use `ind` to index `prev_array`, and calculate the new (subtracted) y coords:

```
new_array = prev_array[ind]
new_array[:,1] = cur_y - new_array[:,1]
```

Giving your final output array:

```
array([[3943,  -61],
       [3945,   10]])
```

As its not clear what you want your output to actually look like, instead of creating a new array, you can also just update `prev_array` with the new y values:

```
ind = (bubble_size > prev_array[:,0]*.95) & (bubble_size < prev_array[:,0]*1.05)
prev_array[ind,1] = cur_y - prev_array[ind,1]
```

Which gives:

```
array([[14040,    42],
       [ 3943,   -61],
       [ 6345,    11],
       [ 3945,    10],
       [    0,     0]])
```